# How do you point an android (ionic) app at a test server if app is Google Play test release?

Tags: android, testing, ionic-framework

When you want to test your android ionic app and point it to a test server (and you want others to be able to test it as well), what's the best practice approach for this?

Can you have the app check if it's running as a test release, and if so, use the test server? Or is there some better way to do this?

EDIT: I would like to publish the app to the Google Play store, and if it's a test release, have the app use the test server, but if it's a production release, then the app would use the production server.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you can use angular environment (baseUrl) like in usual angular web-app, and just add `--prod` or `--test` as a parameter.

for example:

```
ionic capacitor copy android --prod
```

Comment: Updated question and title above. Basically, is there a way for the app to know it it's running as a Google Play store test release vs. a Google Play store production release?